# Can Windows Server 2012 be used as an everyday OS?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, windows-server-2012, dreamspark

So all the major computer smarties are probably dying in laughter at seeing this question but I'm being serious. I had to wipe my laptop and install Ubuntu since I no longer had the installation disk for Windows 7 Ultimate. I'm going to come right out and say it. After using Windows my whole life I can't stand Linux/Ubuntu. I have to go back to some form of Windows but I have no extra money to spend on buying a new Windows disc (saving up for a new laptop). I have the ability to get Windows Server 2012 for free (Dreamspark) and I am wondering if I could use it as an everyday operating system. I like to play game on my laptop and I also use it during school for schoolwork and not taking. Would I be able to do all of this on the Windows Server 2012 OS? Thanks!

Comment: Have you acquired your `Windows 7 Ultimate` OS legally? Could you find  a _Certificate of Authenticity_ label somewhere on the case? Read [answer by Ronnie VernonMVP, Moderator Wednesday, March 17, 2010 2:12 AM](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3ec5bec4-570c-4529-8176-6e8930766d5f/buying-a-windows-7-ultimate-key-off-ebay?forum=w7itproinstall)

Comment: @JoesefZ The laptop was supplied through work. They were the ones who set up the laptop originally.

Comment: I am not sure Dreamspark allows the use of a PC for everyday use. Its more for your development and testing purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You need to add the Desktop Experience feature which is somehow hidden.
In order to activate it via the **Server Manager**, select **Add Roles and Features**. When **Features** comes up, expand the **User Interfaces and Infrastructure** feature and select the **Desktop Experience** component.

Comment: +1 because I think this answers the OPs question in the most succint way. Still posting a longer answer because I think it is the hard way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to give two answers:

1) Yes. You can use server 2012 as a desktop OS. However you will face some additional challenges.

- For starters you need to add the desktop experience feature. @GI) already described that.
- Another issue are drivers. Most are written for a specific OS and will refuse to install on an OS which does not match. You can try to force install drivers, but stability is not guaranteed.

2) Why even bother with Server 2012. If the laptop came with a legal windows 7 (and since you got it from a workplace I might hope that it was legal), then you can just ask for the original CoA. With that and an easily found windows 7 DVD you can install the original OS.

Comment: Well see the thing is, it's my mother's laptop (I'm 16) but she gave it to me to use. She was let go from the company but on good terms so they let her keep the laptop. We have no way of getting the installation disk

Comment: I've never seen a problem installing drivers. It's _antivirus software_ that will refuse to install.

Comment: Getting the disc (or the iso) is not a problem. Those are available on the net. (See (this post)[http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft] on how to download a legal iso. Getting sunch a disc never was a problem. The challenge is a legal CoA. Which is usually on a sticker on the laptop, though it might be hidden behind the battery compartment (e.g. with Dells) or in other places.